# Demotivating test reviews

Tags: discussion, review, review-audit

Some of the posts I review as candidates for deletion are test items. After I duly pass or condemn such an item, I get the message

**Congratulations! This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. You passed.**

I know that, rationally, I should not let a robot irritate me. But this particular bot does a very good impression of a strict teacher repeatedly checking up on a disreputable 9-year-old at the back of the classroom, whom I am presumed to be, and I am impressed. Each time it happens, it reduces my motivation to review further. In fact, at this rate, my future service as a reviewer is likely to be a short one.

I am glad that other people, more rational than me, continue to clean up Math Stack Exchange by doing reviews. I wish I could be more like them.

A question arises: could the frequency of review tests be reduced (even to zero) for people who pass enough of them and/or have enough reputation points? A related question is: if such tests are necessary, could they be made more searching than, for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/986434) test that I was given?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Usually we get complaints about the failure text. :-)

Comment: @ZacharySelk: I have added a question, and another for good measure.

Comment: Related feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: [Gradually lowering the frequency of review audits for users proven to be trustworthy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226275).

Comment: My solution to this problem is to stop doing reviews. It works great: I haven't felt irritated by the test reviews in years!

Comment: Before any change in the policy, a possible workaround is to take a look at the creation date and user reputation before reading the content.

Comment: The frequency of tests _is_ reduced to zero. I'm not sure by exactly what mechanism, but I've not seen one for years. I think it must take total network rep into account as I don't remember when I last saw a test question even on sites such as this one where I have only just enough rep to review.

Comment: Another reason why I'm not interested in getting to 10k or even 1k.

Comment: The last time I got tested I was skipping through off-topic close votes very quickly. I think the system thought I was some kind of robot and decided to throw out a speed bump just to be sure.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks well, you are *not* forced to review even though you have access to it. You can still do any moderation outside the review queue, but yeah... getting 10k will allow you to see all (mostly discouragingly bad) deleted posts :)

Comment: Question for the mods: is this a setting that we, as a community, can control, or is it set site-wide by the SO staff? If the former, then I very much agree this is a conversation worth having. As another piece of anecdotal evidence, I very seldom do any reviews anymore due to getting fed up with the constant "tests."

Comment: I got tested today for the first time in several months. I recognized the test question, it was a question that I had looked at and thought about answering last week. For some reason I thought they actually made up questions for the sole purpose of using them in these test reviews.